# How to listen for successful operation using ngrx

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have a Angular2 application using ngrx Store and Effects. Everything works great however I'm not sure the best way to handle **knowing** when a service call operation has successfully completed in order to update the view with a success alert or similar.

For instance, this is my flow when on a CreateUser view.

1. View dispatches Action to Effect
2. Effect calls service to create user
3. Service returns success result to Effect (in our case an updated User Object)
4. Effect updates the Store via a new state via the Reducer.

Now I would like to signify to the user that the operation completed successful, but I don't know the best way to handle this.

Do I setup an Observable to the store on the CreateUser component to detect the change via a selector, or is there a more appropriate method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are virtually endless ways to do this, here is an example on how to do this via the ngrx-store and effects:

1. ...
2. ...
3. Service returns success result to Effect (in our case an updated User Object)
4. Effect emits `UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS_ACTION`. Together with the success-action the effect emits another action
   `RESET_UPDATE_EVENT_ACTION` (or you can setup a separate effect for
   this if you prefer)

The reducer handles those actions the following way:

UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS_ACTION:

- Updates the user-object of course
- sets a flag in the store: `userWasUpdated: true`

RESET_UPDATE_EVENT_ACTION:

- sets a flag in the store: `userWasUpdated: false`

And in your component you do the following:

```
userWasUpdated$ = this.store$
    .select(state => state.userWasUpdated) // this will only trigger when the value changed, because ngrxStore.select has a built-in distinctUntilChanged()
    .filter(wasUpdated => wasUpdated)  // we are only in "truthy" events, so we filter out the other events
```

And with `userWasUpdated$` you now have an `Observable`, that emits whenever the userObject was updated successfully.

---

Sounds like a lot of code? Yup, it is. Whenever possible my personal solution is to create some notification-service that shows a toast/alert and I call it directly from within the effect.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. This is very similar to what I ended up doing. I implemented a toast service as well, and in the effect I dispatch a Message object with "showToast" so I can control when that shows or if the view handles everything itself.

Comment: I have been waiting for this !